# VBA Scraping End With or Object Errors (no solution from other examples)

Tags: vba

I have gone through every other possible post which is some variation of this but cant see to figure out why the compiler keeps complaining on the code that is bolded. I have tried seeing if I have declared my objects with a "Set" and even seen if my "End With" block was properly done. I have compared with other code as well but I am pulling my hair on this one. Any help to point me in the right direction so I can start scraping the listings and pour the information into Excel.

Thanks again **V3==================================================================**

**Code in Question** 
Even though I am using the classnames from the results page VBA only grabs "randomly" instead of the entire "column" of results (class name= "results col" which I tried to grab by making a new "case" but I am wondering if it should go first instead of last. Thanks a bunch again.

```
Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
  DoEvents
Loop

For Each ele In .document.all
Select Case ele.classname
**Case "jobtitle turnstileLink" 'The jobname result
RowCount = RowCount + 1
**Case "company" 'the company name '
sht.Range("A" & RowCount) = ele.innertext
**Case "location" 'location of job '
sht.Range("B" & RowCount) = ele.innertext
**Case "summary" 'Job Description '
sht.Range("C" & RowCount) = ele.innertext
End Select
Next
```

**=========================================**

```
Sub test()
Dim eRow As Long
Dim ele As Object
'Dim IE As Object
Dim objIE
'Dim objElement As Object
'Dim objCollection As Object
Dim sht
Dim myJobType, myZip As String
Dim zipcode, What As Object  'Created this Dim objects '
'Dim Sheet1 As Worksheets 'referencing sheets?' this causes error
'referencing the "sheet1" with ws variable '
Dim ws As Worksheet


'Duplicate'
'Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")


Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1")



RowCount = 1
sht.Range("A" & RowCount) = "Title"
sht.Range("B" & RowCount) = "Company"
sht.Range("C" & RowCount) = "Location"
sht.Range("D" & RowCount) = "Description"


'===============================================================================
'eRow = Sheet1.Cells(rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
'you reference Sheet1, which is not set previously (while sht is)

'eRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
'=============================================================================

eRow = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

myJobType = InputBox("Enter type of job eg. sales, administration")
myZip = InputBox("Enter zipcode of area where you wish to work")

With objIE
.Visible = True
.navigate "http://www.indeed.com"

MsgBox "Visting Webpage"
Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
DoEvents
Loop

'Enter job name/type '
Set What = .document.getElementsByName("q")
What.Item(0).Value = myJobType

'changed WHERE to 'l' as that is the name of the zipcode textbox
Set zipcode = .document.getElementsByName("l")
'objectVariableIssue not set
zipcode.Item(0).Value = myZip

'Click webpage button' , changed to "fj" which is the find jobs button
.document.getElementById("fj").Click

'code throwing object errors'
'===================================================================='
'Complains of object required error 424
''.document.getElementById("submit").Click

'This "clicks" the submit button'
'This is complaining of object error, along with the line commented
'out previously.

'runtime error 91,object variable or  block variable not set.
'IE.document.forms(0).click

'IE.document.getElementById("jobsdotcom").Click'
'============================================================='



'======================================================================'
'Wait for webpage to fully load, and loop through elements'
'This is the  second DoEvents Loop We dont need this
'Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
'MsgBox "Visting Website"
  'DoEvents
'Loop
'============================================================================='

Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
  DoEvents
Loop

For Each ele In .document.all
Select Case ele.classname
Case "jobtitle turnstileLink" 'The jobname result
RowCount = RowCount + 1
Case "company" 'the company name '
sht.Range("A" & RowCount) = ele.innertext
Case "location" 'location of job '
sht.Range("B" & RowCount) = ele.innertext
Case "summary" 'Job Description '
sht.Range("C" & RowCount) = ele.innertext
Case "row result" 
sht.Range("D" & RowCount) = ele.innertext
    End Select
Next

Set objIE = Nothing
End With 'Moved from before
End Sub
```

**V3==================================================================**

**myZip = InputBox("Enter zipcode of area where you wish to work")**

**V2**==========================================================

**Thanks a bunch, I think I became younger just from that you guys. Here are some changes I made below Excel now complains on:**

```
eRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
```

**I have declared Sheet 1 with**

```
Dim sht 
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
```

**But I still get the error "Run Timer Error 91, Object variable with block variable not set"**

Thank You x1 Million.

```
Sub test()
Dim eRow As Long
Dim ele As Object
'Dim IE As Object
Dim objIE
'Dim objElement As Object
'Dim objCollection As Object
Dim sht
Dim myJobType, myZip As Object
Dim zipcode, What As Object  'Created this Dim objects '
Dim Sheet1 As Worksheets 'referencing sheets?'
'referencing the "sheet1" with ws variable '
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")


Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1")



RowCount = 1
sht.Range("A" & RowCount) = "Title"
sht.Range("B" & RowCount) = "Company"
sht.Range("C" & RowCount) = "Location"
sht.Range("D" & RowCount) = "Description"

'eRow = Sheet1.Cells(rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
'you reference Sheet1, which is not set previously (while sht is)

eRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

myJobType = InputBox("Enter type of job eg. sales, administration")
myZip = InputBox("Enter zipcode of area where you wish to work")

With objIE
.Visible = True
.navigate "http://www.indeed.com"

Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
  DoEvents
Loop

'Enter job name/type '
Set What = .document.getElementsByName("q")
What.Item(0).Value = myJobType

'changed WHERE to 'l' as that is the name of the zipcode textbox
Set zipcode = .document.getElementsByName("l")
'objectVariableIssue not set
zipcode.Item(0).Value = myZip

'code throwing object errors'
'===================================================================='
'Complains of object required error 424
''.document.getElementById("submit").Click

'This "clicks" the submit button'
'This is complaining of object error, along with the line commented
'out previously.

'runtime error 91,object variable or  block variable not set.
'IE.document.forms(0).click

'IE.document.getElementById("jobsdotcom").Click'
'============================================================='
'Click webpage button' , changed to "fj" which is the find jobs button
.document.getElementById("fj").Click

'Wait for webpage to fully load, and loop through elements'
Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
  DoEvents
Loop

For Each ele In .document.all
Select Case ele.classname
Case "Result"
RowCount = RowCount + 1
Case "Title"
sht.Range("A" & RowCount) = ele.innertext
Case "Company"
sht.Range("B" & RowCount) = ele.innertext
Case "Location"
sht.Range("C" & RowCount) = ele.innertext
Case "Description"
sht.Range("D" & RowCount) = ele.innertext
End Select
Next

Set objIE = Nothing
End With 'Moved from before 
End Sub
```

## ==========================================================================

**V1**

```
Sub test()
Dim eRow As Long
Dim ele As Object
'Dim IE As Object
Dim objIE
'Dim objElement As Object
'Dim objCollection As Object
Dim sht
Dim myJobType, myZip
Dim zipcode, what


Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1")



RowCount = 1
sht.Range("A" & RowCount) = "Title"
sht.Range("B" & RowCount) = "Company"
sht.Range("C" & RowCount) = "Location"
sht.Range("D" & RowCount) = "Description"

eRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

myJobType = InputBox("Enter type of job eg. sales, administration")
myZip = InputBox("Enter zipcode of area where you wish to work")

With objIE
.Visible = True
.navigate "http://www.indeed.com"

Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
  DoEvents
Loop

'Enter job name/type '
Set what = .document.getElementsByName("q")
what.Item(0).Value = myJobType


Set zipcode = .document.getElementsByName("where")
'objectVariableIssue not set
zipcode.Item(0).Value = myZip

'code throwing object errors'
'===================================================================='
'Complains of object required error 424
''.document.getElementById("submit").Click

'This "clicks" the submit button'
'This is complaining of object error, along with the line commented
'out previously.

'runtime error 91,object variable or  block variable not set.
'IE.document.forms(0).click

'IE.document.getElementById("jobsdotcom").Click'
'============================================================='
'Click webpage button'
.document.getElementById("input_submit").Click

'Wait for webpage to fully load, and loop through elements'
Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
  DoEvents
Loop

For Each ele In .document.all
Select Case ele.classname
Case "Result"
RowCount = RowCount + 1
Case "Title"
sht.Range("A" & RowCount) = ele.innertext
Case "Company"
sht.Range("B" & RowCount) = ele.innertext
Case “Location”
sht.Range("C" & RowCount) = ele.innertext
Case "Description"
sht.Range("D" & RowCount) = ele.innertext
End Select
Next

Set objIE = Nothing
End With 'Moved from before End Sub
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as for the "ZIP code" error you must type

```
Set zipcode = .document.getElementsByName("l")
```

since `"l"` (not `"where"`) is the actual name of the ZIP textbox

moreover, I'd point out the following:

in

```
eRow = Sheet1.Cells(rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
```

you reference `Sheet1`, which is not set previously (while `sht` is)

in

```
Case “Location”
```

you're using "strange" quotation marks (different than those used in the rest of the code)

Comment: those quotes really annoyed me , the whole issue was I was trying to piece together fragments, where Initially I started using the tag "l" and ended up to "where". But no more errors Galore. But I thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome. Copy&pasting is a useful way of doing it but also an error prone activity. You'd better always use "Option Explicit" keyword at the very top of your module: at the expense of some little extra work (you'll have to explicitly declare ALL variables) you'll earn back much more control over your code. Finally If I fullfilled your original question please mark the answer as accepted. Thank you

Comment: I was wondering if you could tell me why the line "eRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row" is still causing object errors even though I declared Sheet1.  Thank you again

Comment: Specify the exact error message and show updated code and have the whole scenario to analyze

Comment: Hi @user3598756 I have added the issue under "V2" of the post. Thanks again

Comment: you're setting both `ws` and `sht` variables to reference `Worksheets("Sheet1")` and then you're trying to use `Sheet1` as a worksheet reference variable which has not been set! You declare `Dim Sheet1 As Worksheets` and not using it. -> I believe you could: 1)  use only `Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1") ` and delete `Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")`; 2) substitute `eRow = Sheet1.Cells(..` with `eRow = sht.Cells(..`; 3) delete `Dim Sheet1 As Worksheets`

Comment: THANK YOU so much (sorry for the caps). The program you helped me with is literally only couple lines away from  being fully completed. I have shown the issues under the section "V3". If you would be so kind to help finalize this program. I don't understand why vba is not grabbing "every" element even though the Loop is digging through every inner element. You are the best.

Comment: You'd better follow the rules of SO and post a new question with only the new issue(s) so as to give a clear scenario to people and let them help you in a more effective way. As for the original question you opened this thread with, if my answer fulfilled it then mark it as accepted. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This line raises a 91 error because you literally do not have in scope a variable called `IE`:

```
IE.document.forms(0).click
```

This line raises the 424 error because there is no such element. Whenever you get the this sort of error, this means that something which *should* be an object, is actually a `Nothing`.

```
.document.getElementById("submit").Click
```

On the requested URL, there is no such element ID as `"submit"`. The `getElementByID` method will return `Nothing`, if the specified ID does not exist on the document.

Assuming you intend to click the "Find Jobs" button, use the appropriate ID value, `"fj"`

[image]

To help trap this, my preferred method is using an appropriate object variable, like:

```
Dim btn as Object
Set btn = .document.getElementById("submit")
If btn Is Nothing
    MsgBox "submit button doesn't exist!", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If
btn.Click()
```

Comment: Thanks made the change I initially had used .document.form(0).submit it wasn't working (I'm guessing I wasn't referencing the ID)